# Literature on nonlinear dictionary learning

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

Can anyone direct me to some literature on learning nonlinear dictionaries? I don't mean sparse dictionaries specifically, but for example learning kernel parameters, or learning $W$ where $y = \phi(Wx)$ and $\phi$ is a fixed nonlinear function. There seems to be fairly well established methods when $\phi$ is linear, but I haven't found much for nonlinear. thanks!